# Pandas comparing each date in a column with other and setting a flag if it isn't?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, filter

### Hi everyone i was going through some YouTube tutorials on Pandas dataframe and came across a problem when i tried filtering dates on a coloumn:

*I made a dummy csv file like below:*

```
Name,State,Date
Mike,Kansas,April7 2018
Charlie,Dubai,7April2018
Amanda,Oregon,07-04-2018
Samantha,Florida,07-04-2018
Tivan,Miami,07-04-2018
Pedro,Mexico,07-04-2018
Lionel,NYC,07-04-2018
Claire,Washington,07-04-2018
Linsday,Texas,07-04-2018
```

*From the csv above what i was trying to do was to find a way so that all dates are compared to check if they are all of the same format and if they aren't then i need to set a flag for the same.* *Here is my code:*

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("SampleFile.csv")
date_parameter = df["Date"][0]
date_list = df["Date"].tolist()
flag = 0
for x in date_list:
    if x == date_parameter:
        # both captured date and dates in "Date" oolumn
        flag = 0
    else:
        # if the date captured isn't consistent ie not of a single date format 
        # then set flag
        flag +=1
print "Finished searching file, the value of the flag is:\n", flag
```

**But it always shows the value as 0, how can i correct my mistake, or is there a better way to do the same. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Can you add link to youtube tutorial? What is expected output?

Comment: Expected output is in the last line.

Comment: "Finished searching the file, the value of the flag is:8" because the first value was compared with the  rest of the col's rows and there were 8 places that didn''t had the same date format as the zeroth row

Comment: I think the best is change question what you need exactly, because need count not equal by first value of date column? Or custom date? Or custom date exclude NaNs? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare first value for not equal `!=` and `sum` `True`s values:

```
flag = (df['Date'] != df.loc[0, 'Date']).sum()
print "Finished searching file, the value of the flag is:\n", flag
Finished searching file, the value of the flag is:
 8
```

**Detail**:

```
print ((df['Date'] != df.loc[0, 'Date']))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

---

If want count not equal and non `NaN`s values compare it separately and chain boolean mask by `&` (bitwise AND, because working with arrays):

```
print (df)
       Name       State         Date
0      Mike      Kansas  April7 2018
1   Charlie       Dubai   7April2018
2    Amanda      Oregon   07-04-2018
3  Samantha     Florida   07-04-2018
4     Tivan       Miami          NaN
5     Pedro      Mexico          NaN
6    Lionel         NYC   07-04-2018
7    Claire  Washington   08-04-2018
8   Linsday       Texas   07-04-2018
```

```
print (df['Date'] != '7April2018')
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool

print (df['Date'].notnull())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool

print ((df['Date'] != '7April2018') & df['Date'].notnull())
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

```
flag = ((df['Date'] != '7April2018') & df['Date'].notnull()).sum()
print (flag)
6
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked like a charm, but i have another querry

Comment: @Kronos - Yop, what is your next query?

Comment: is  it possible to just search the date column and check in one go whether all dates are of the same format and are not null

Comment: for instance say that i want to ensure that no rows in the date col have date in format other than 7April,2018 and at the same time no row should be empty can i do that in one go

Comment: @Kronos - Do you think `flag = ((df['Date'] != '7April2018') & df['Date'].notnull()).sum()` ?

Comment: but i can't clearly understand what the != and sum are doing in this line

Comment: if (df["date"] != '7April,2018') & (df["date"].notnull()):

Comment: First the best is forget for loops, in pandas is best avoid it.

Comment: because .sum is returning 9 which is the numeber of times it doesen't get the date as 7April,2018 instead of returning flag = 1 implying there was a date mismatch and the flag has been set to 1 as a result

Comment: @Kronos - Sorry, now I am a bit confused what you need. Answer was edited, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in 0 = no mismatch or 1 = mismatch then you could use the `any()` function in python.

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Name,State,Date
Mike,Kansas,April7 2018
Charlie,Dubai,7April2018
Amanda,Oregon,07-04-2018
Samantha,Florida,07-04-2018
Tivan,Miami,07-04-2018
Pedro,Mexico,07-04-2018
Lionel,NYC,07-04-2018
Claire,Washington,07-04-2018
Linsday,Texas,07-04-2018'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=',')

flag = (df['Date'] != '7April2018').any().astype(int)

print(flag)
```

Returns: `1`